# Drive letter in subpaths of Path

Tags: java

Please consider the following code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class TestPath {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String filename = "c:/manyOthers/dir1/dir2/dir3";
        File f = new File(filename);
        String absPathS = f.getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println(absPathS);
        
        // now I try to add a timestamp between dir1 and dir2/dir3 in abstPathS
        Path absPath = Paths.get(absPathS);
        int n = absPath.getNameCount();
        String timestamp = "20210308";
        
        Path subpath = absPath.subpath(0, n-2);
        Path outPath = Paths.get(subpath.toString(), timestamp, absPath.subpath(n-2, n).toString());
        System.out.println("Timestamped: " + outPath);
    }   
}
```

The output is:

```
c:\manyOthers\dir1\dir2\dir3
Timestamped: manyOthers\dir1\20210308\dir2\dir3
```

Basically - in my actual code - I receive the absolute path to a folder and I need to insert a subfolder whose name corresponds to a timestamp. The code above is just an example, I am using it here for providing a simple running example; in the actual code the path contains many more subfolders `c:/folder1/folder2/.../dir1/dir2/dir3`, so, please, if you intend to answer this question, do not tailor the solution to the specific code above.

In the code above, I have the absolute path `C:/manyOthers/dir1/dir2/dir3/` and I need to insert a timestamp between `dir1` and `dir2/dir3`. However, as you can see, **the problem is that the final output has lost the drive letter**.

I have read elsewhere that in Java there are no ways to add back that `c:/`, but it would be weird ince the prefix `c:\` is returned by functions as `File.getAbsolutePath()`. For example:

```
File f = new File("any");
System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

prints:

```
C:\Users\user\workspace\project\any
```

How I can keep / re-insert the drive letter in my paths?

Comment: `System.out.println("Timestamped: " + outPath.toAbsolutePath());`?

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work because the current working directory is prefixed to outPath. I could mess around using string tokenization, but I would rather use the Path library.

Comment: `abs.getRoot().resolve(abs.subpath(0, n-2)).resolve(timestamp).resolve(abs.subpath(n-2,n))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `Path.subPath` always returns a relative path.

But fortunately your `Path absPath` is absolute and contains `C:\` as the root. So you can get that via `absPath.getRoot()`.

Having this you can create `Path outPath` from that root:

```
...
Path outPath = Paths.get(absPath.getRoot().toString(), subpath.toString(), timestamp, absPath.subpath(n-2, n).toString());
...
```

As @user15244370 commented, the whole thing could be done much more elegant using `Path.resolve` without using `Paths` and `Path.toString`.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class TestPath {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String filename = "c:/manyOthers/dir1/dir2/dir3";
        
        Path absPath = Paths.get(filename);
        System.out.println("Source path: " + absPath);

        int n = absPath.getNameCount();
        String timestamp = "20210308";
        
        Path subpath = absPath.subpath(0, n-2);
        Path outPath = absPath.getRoot().resolve(subpath).resolve(timestamp).resolve(absPath.subpath(n-2, n));
        System.out.println("Timestamped: " + outPath);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks! After your message and looking for information about what "root" is, I have found the documentation I needed in getParent(). Cheers.